# getting same elements and changing values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which I have the same webpart appearing multiple times.The issue is the z index as when the dropdown in the webpart control opens up the same webpart which is placed down below hides it since it also has the same z index.So I am trying to get all the elements in the page with the class and then want to loop through them decrementing the z index as the webpart control appears down on the page.

So if there are 3 instances of the control the first one gets a z index 60 the second gets 50 and the third gets 40.All the controls can be selected the below was using the class .So if someone can tell me how I can get a reference to all the elements which have the class inside class patern and then loop through them and then assign the z index.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.Wrapper .selectbox').css('z-index', '100');


});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$($('.Wrapper .selectbox').get().reverse()).each(function(i){
    $(this).css('z-index', i * 20);
});
```

Or if you want to clean this up, create a simple function:

```
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
```

and use this syntax:

```
$('.Wrapper .selectbox')reverse().each(function(i){
    $(this).css('z-index', i * 20);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying .I am using the below code and  it seems to be working fineDo you see any performance issue with this .$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var val = 100;
    $('.Wrapper .selectbox').each(function (i, obj) {      
        
        $(this).css('z-index', val);
        val = val-10;

    });

});

Comment: Nope, just plan on having 10 or fewer items, or reduce the delta between z-indexes.